# Efficient sum, vector-matrix-vector by Fortran

Tags: algorithm, loops, nested, fortran, blas

I want to compute the summation more efficient. There are nested loops, which I want to avoid.

! If i+j <= I,then A_{j} = \sum_{m,n,i} C_{m, i+j} G_{ m, n, i, j} C_{n, i}

! else if i+j >= I, then A_{j} = \sum_{m,n,i} C_{m, i+j-I} G_{ m, n, i, j} C_{n, i}

```
program main
  implicit none
  real, allocatable :: A(:)
  real, allocatable :: C(:,:), G(:,:,:,:)
  integer :: i, j, m, n
  integer, parameter :: N = 1500, I = 2000

  allocate(A(J))
  allocate(C(N,I))
  allocate(G(N,N,I,I))
  ! If i+j <= I,then
  ! A_{j} = \sum_{m,n,i} C_{m, i+j} G_{ m, n, i, j} C_{n, i} 
  ! else if i+j >= I, then
  ! A_{j} = \sum_{m,n,i} C_{m, i+j-I} G_{ m, n, i, j} C_{n, i}
  do j = 1, I
    do i = 1, I
      if ( i + j <= I ) then
        do n = 1, N
          do m = 1, N
            A(j) = A(j) + C(m,i+j) * G(m,n,i,j) * C(n,i)
          end do
        end do
      else
        do n = 1, N
          do m = 1, N
            A(j) = A(j) + C(m,i+j-I) * G(m,n,i,j) * C(n,i)
          end do
        end do
      end if
    end do
  end do
  
end program main
```

Comment: Before worrying about efficiency, it would be wise to consider that you are trying to name a variable and a constant the same. `i` and `I` are not distinct names, and hopefully your compiler is telling you that. (If it isn't, it's time to change compiler.)

Comment: Are you aware of [matmul](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MATMUL.html)?

Comment: Might be an idea to assign some values to C and G (and A) before using them.

Comment: What's inherently wrong with nested loops? Fortran compilers are often very good at optimising loop nests

Comment: Mao Yang - your array G(:,:,:,:) has nine trillion (9e12) elements. I think that reordering loops is possibly the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by addressing @francescalus' comment, and rename `I` and `N`. Let's call them `II` and `NN`. No, this is not a good naming convention, but I don't know what these variables actually are.

Let's also assume you've initialised your variables, as per @lastchance's comment.

The first thing that leaps out is the lines

```
do j=1,II
  do i=1,II
    if (i+j <= II) then
      ...
    else
      ...
```

this loop-with-an-if-inside can be replaced with a couple of loops with no if, which is usually a good idea. Something like:

```
do j=1,II
  do i=1,II-j
    ...
  end do
  do i=II-j+1,II
    ...
  end do
```

Now let's use [matmul](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MATMUL.html) to clean up the loops over `m` and `n`, something like:

```
do j=1,II
  do i=1,II-j
    A(j) = A(j) + dot_product(matmul(C(:,i+j), G(:,:,i,j)), C(:,i))
  end do
  do i=II-j+1,II
    A(j) = A(j) + dot_product(matmul(C(:,i+j-I), G(:,:,i,j)), C(:,i))
  end do
end do
```

Note that this isn't doing any less work than your code (and indeed, since you're looping over all four indices of `G`, doing less work doesn't look possible), but it should at least do the work a little more efficiently.